# c++ warning: enumeration value not handled in switch [-Wswitch]

Tags: c++, switch-statement, warnings, compiler-warnings

I am trying to compile following code without warnings:

```
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        switch (event.type) {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close(); break;
            case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                if(event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape )
                    window.close();
                if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed( sf::Keyboard::Space ) )
                    particleSystem.fuel( 200/* * window.getFrameTime() */);
                if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed( sf::Keyboard::A ) )
                    particleSystem.setPosition( --xpos, ypos );
                if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed( sf::Keyboard::D ) )
                    particleSystem.setPosition( ++xpos, ypos );
                if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed( sf::Keyboard::W ) )
                    particleSystem.setPosition( xpos, --ypos );
                if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed( sf::Keyboard::S ) )
                    particleSystem.setPosition( xpos, ++ypos );
                if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed( sf::Keyboard::Left ) )
                    particleSystem.setGravity( --xgrv * 0.1f, ygrv * 0.1f);
                if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed( sf::Keyboard::Right ) )
                    particleSystem.setGravity( ++xgrv * 0.1f, ygrv * 0.1f );
                if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed( sf::Keyboard::Up ) )
                    particleSystem.setGravity( xgrv * 0.1f, --ygrv * 0.1f );
                if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed( sf::Keyboard::Down ) )
                    particleSystem.setGravity( xgrv * 0.1f, ++ygrv * 0.1f );
                if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed( sf::Keyboard::G ) )
                    particleSystem.setGravity( 0.0f, 0.0f );
                if( sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed( sf::Keyboard::P ) )
                    particleSystem.setPosition( 320.0f, 240.0f );
                break;
    }
```

however, I am getting a lot of warnings:

```
/home/bluszcz/private/repo/deerportal/game.cpp:444: warning: enumeration value 'LostFocus' not handled in switch [-Wswitch]
```

Which in my it is not an issue, since I am don't need handling all types of the events.

Adding

```
default:
    break;
```

to my code removes the warnings, however is it a best way to solve this issue?

Comment: I think `default` is still the best way, you can still handle every event separately if you want to.

Comment: You should almost always have a default case in case there is no match.

Comment: I personally believe this warning (together with reordering of member initialization in constructor) is one of the least useful in gcc. I had tons of cases where not all enum values had a meaningful case switches, and doing an empty default just to pacify the compiler is meaningless syntax noise. That's why this warning is the one I am OK with suppressing.

Comment: @NathanOliver I disagree. Sure, there are cases where a `default:` case is appropriate. But in the general case you should avoid it and handle all values explicitly so that the compiler can warn you when you forgot to handle a case.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### Be explicit

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. The governing rule is

> It is better to be explicit.

Omitting the cases simply makes it look like you forgot some. Being explicit assures subsequent readers of your code that you *intended* to do nothing for certain events.

In light of that, you have a couple of options:

### Option 1 - add the default

```
default:
  break;
```

This suppresses the warning, and makes it clear that you don't intend to handle the other event types here.

### Option 2 - list each value

List each event type, followed by a `break`.
This is also explicit, and has the added bonus that, should you ever add an event type, the compiler will once again warn you that your `switch` is incomplete. This can be valuable when you have many switch statements, some of which need to be modified to do something new when an enum value is added.

### What about a series of if statements?

I would not recommend using a series of `if` statements here. A `switch` is clearer, reduces the amount of typing, and (as you've seen) can produce better compiler warnings for cases you omitted.

Comment: Nice argumentation of Option 2, however in my simply case where I am interested only of particular events handling, I think Option 1 is my case. Thank you.

Comment: Option 1 did the job for me!

Comment: For option 2 you could also list all event types and put `break` only after the last one.

Comment: @Dino that's certainly possible, and my original statement wasn't specific about _where_ the `break` should live - i.e. is each one followed by a `break`, or only the last one? I would, however, advise following each case with a `break`, as compilers tend to warn about fall-through in switch statements, and if one of them was ever edited to do something meaningful, the fall-through logic may accidentally not be updated, which could cause problems. A few more characters typed, to save ourselves from pain later!

Comment: It seems to me with '-DSHOW_WARNINGS=1', GNU make version 3.81 doesn't suppress warnings with Option 1. These lines are still seen.  
```11: warning: enumeration value 'ABC' not explicitly handled in switch [-Wswitch-enum]. 
11: note: add missing switch cases
```