# How to disable "enumeration value not explicitly handled in switch" just for one block of switch case?

Tags: c++, clang, qt-creator

Can you tell me how to disable the compiler/codemodel warning for just one block of switch/case?

In general, I think it is very useful to be warned, but here it complains about 167 enumeration values not explicitly handled in the `switch`.

I found this other question:

[c++ warning: enumeration value not handled in switch [-Wswitch]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37254496/)

It says that you can get rid of the warning with `default: break;` but in this case (recent QtCreator with clang) this does not apply.

I know I could change the code to `if/else if/else if ..` but I expect the list of handled cases will grow with time, so I'd prefer to stay with `switch/case`.

So, my question is, is there any keyword/macro/comment/attribute that says ignore the issue for just this single block?

The following code produces the warning, the other 167 values seem to be the possible return values of `QEvent::type()`, which are part of Qt:

```
bool MyClass::event(QEvent * e) {
    switch(e->type()) {
    case QEvent::HoverEnter:
        qDebug() << "enter"; 
        return true;
    case QEvent::HoverLeave:
        qDebug() << "leave"; 
        return true;
    case QEvent::HoverMove:
        qDebug() << "move"; 
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return Piece::event(e);
}
```

Comment: isnt this the advantage of using a `switch` ? when "the list of handled cases will grow with time" you cannot easily miss one because you get that warning. Can you show a [mcve]? would be interesting to see why `default` doesnt help

Comment: i guess what makes the difference is the "explicitly". You do handle all cases, but not explicitly

Comment: please also add the warning verbatim in the question

Comment: @user463035818: can you explain what you mean? I only want to handle three cases for now, later maybe 10 or 20, but in total there are about 170 and most of them I'll never need.

Comment: i think you are confusing `-Wswitch` and `-Wswitch-enum`. The other question is about the first and can be silenced by a `default`, the warning about the "not explicitly handled case" is from the second. I think you just need enable the first and disable the second.

Comment: see eg here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#w-warnings

Comment: maybe i confused the two, but how can i disable it only for this one switch, and keep it enabled for all others?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078941/how-to-use-pragma-clang-diagnostics) is not really a dupe, but the question has the answer

Comment: thanks a lot! works with pragma and "-Wswitch", I'll add it to the question

Comment: you can post an answer to your own question. I am not familiar with clang and wasnt in the mood to find out to be sure enough to write an answer, but imho your edit should be rather an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in comment by user463035818 the message can be disabled for specific part of code by adding #pragma:

```
bool MyClass::event(QEvent * e) {
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch"
    switch(e->type()) {
    case QEvent::HoverEnter:
        qDebug() << "enter"; 
        return true;
    case QEvent::HoverLeave:
        qDebug() << "leave"; 
        return true;
    case QEvent::HoverMove:
        qDebug() << "move"; 
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
    return Piece::event(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer posted by user2567875, if you are using the GCC build-tool., you can get the same like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch"
switch(...)
{
...
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Notice that `GCC` must be capital.